The Linear (In)Dependence of Rows of $\mathbf{X}$ and (Non)Trivial Solutions to $\mathbf{Xa}=\mathbf{0}$.
Let $\mathbf{X}$ be an $m\times n$ matrix. Let $\mathbf{a}$ be an $n\times1$ vector. Consider the homogeneous equations:
$$
\mathbf{Xa}=\mathbf{0}.
$$
It is known that the columns of $\mathbf{X}$ are linearly dependent if and only if $\mathbf{Xa}=\mathbf{0}$ for some $\mathbf{a}\neq\mathbf{0}$.
My Question
Now my question is that can we have a similar proposition for the rows of $\mathbf{X}$?
I constructed an example that a matrix $\mathbf{X}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and a column vector $\mathbf{a}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ are such that the rows of $X$ are linearly independent but $\mathbf{Xa}=\mathbf{0}$ for some $\mathbf{a}\neq\mathbf{0}$. This shows that the following statement is FALSE:

Statement 1$\quad$ If the homogeneous equation $\mathbf{Xa}=\mathbf{0}$ has a nontrivial solution, then the rows of $\mathbf{X}$ are linearly dependent.

However, I am having a difficult time constructing a counterexample to show the following statement (reverse direction of the above statement) is FALSE:

Statement 2$\quad$ If the rows of $\mathbf{X}$ are linearly dependent, then the homogeneous equation $\mathbf{Xa}=\mathbf{0}$ has a nontrivial solution.

So my question is: Is the second statement false? If so, could someone please provide a counterexample? If not, could someone please prove it?
Thanks a lot in advance!

PS: A quick confirmation, is the following claim correct if $\mathbf{X}$ is a square matrix:
Claim$\quad$ The following statements are equivalent:

The columns of $\mathbf{X}$ are linearly dependent.
The rows of $\mathbf{X}$ are linearly dependent.
$\mathbf{Xa}=\mathbf{0}$ has a nontrivial solution $\mathbf{a}\neq\mathbf{0}$.
$\mathbf{X}$ is singular; i.e., $\mathbf{X}^{-1}$ does not exist.


Wait, is this a valid counterexample for Statement 2? Let $\mathbf{X}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\0&1&0\0&0&1\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$, and write $\mathbf{a}=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\a_2\a_3\end{pmatrix}$. Then the rows of $\mathbf{X}$ are linearly dependent. But $\mathbf{Xa}=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\a_2\a_3\a_1\end{pmatrix}=\mathbf{0}$ has only the trivial solution.

Take the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Their rows are linearly dependent but the unique solution to the associated homogeneous linear system is the trivial one.
Furthermore, it is not so difficult to prove that Statement $2$  is true if $m \leq n$. Indeed, If the rows are linearly dependent, then the row-rank of the matrix is less than $m$, so that less than $n$. However, the row-rank is equal to the column-rank (important theorem of Linear Algebra) so that the column-rank is less than $n$ and it there exists a nontrivial solution for the system. In this way, I constructed the counterexample. Indeed, you can try to construct several ones starting from the condition $m\geq n+1$.
